# ADF - Copy Data - Add additional column inside ForEach loop dynamic value

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I wish to dynamically add column in Copy Activity inside a foreach loop.
The Copy Activity is inside a for each loop , and the Source table is dynamic value from a lookup table path outside the for each loop.

**Foreach loop:**
[image: Foreach loop]

**Inside foreach loop:**
[image: Inside foreach loop]

The error i get is :

```
Error details
Error code
2200
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
The value of property 'additionalColumns' is in unexpected type 'IList`1'.
Source
Pipeline
TEST_IncrementalLoad.
```

How do i add the dynamic column value in each loop from the lookup table?
i tried to add a parameter, but the result is as above.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the pipeline run output, verify the input to additional column. Share that if possible.

It might be that the value of `@item().CompanyId` is not of **Type** `String`

You can try use the `parameter` of type **Object** if `@item().CompanyId` is not of type `string`.

I tried a similar example and using the iteration item in dynamic column, it works fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edit according to your response with Name and Value tabs.

Comment: @karthik : For Azure SQL it does not show above Name and Value option